# How to create a C# script that allows me to move an sprite/object according to a Grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid

I need to move an object that is on a Grid with C# script.
I use `transform.position = new Vector3 (X, Y, Z)` to move it but it moves according to the Main Grid (that Unity creates by default when you start a new project). 
How I can attach `transform.position` to the grid that I've created?

```
// A3 is the sprite
public class A3 : MonoBehaviour {

    float Y = -0.806043f;
    float X = -1.007555f;
    int Z = -1;

    void Update() 
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (X, Y, Z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic formula for grid movement is this:

```
float TileSize = 1;

Vector3 pos = new Vector3(2.5f, 0.1f, 5.25f);

pos.x = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.x / TileSize) * TileSize;
pos.y = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.y / TileSize) * TileSize;
pos.z = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.z / TileSize) * TileSize;
```

`TileSize: 0.5` => `x:2.5f, y:0f, z:5f`

`TileSize: 1` => `x:2f, y:0f, z:5f`

`TileSize: 2` => `x:2.5f, y:0f, z:4f`

Comment: I'm new to Unity and C#, how can I implement this code?

Comment: I fixed it! Just changed the transform.position to transform.localPosition